# PM project definitions

Tags: definition

What are the definitions, and examples of to show the differences between:
Vision,
Business outcome,
Goal,
Objective,
Requirement,
Scope,
Product.

Comment: What is the specific problem you're facing, and why aren't the easily-available definitions from Google or Wikipedia sufficient to answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

One by one

- **Vision**: in simple words, a dream or a big picture of future. For example You are doing this job to diminish poverty in the world.
- **Objectives**: To diminish the poverty, you have to set reachable objectives. Usually using KISS & SMART
- **Business Outcome**: You have to perform many projects in order to achieve your Objectives. What will you get from Project A, B, and C? these project Outcomes
- **Goal**: sets of small, reachable, and measurable objectives withing your programs, projects, or daily tasks. Total sums of Goals could be Objectives.
- **Requirement**: Diminishing Poverty in the world needs resources (Money, Support, Labour, Time). In other words, the requirement is all you need to make that objective reachable.
- **Scope**: you have to do a lot of works and not to do some works to achieve your goals, and ultimately your objectives.
- **Product**: after all these efforts, you created a box. A box can hand over to poor people and boom; they will be rich. That box is product :)

I think you can figure out the dependency and the interrelationship of them yourself :)

cheers, 
Rasoul Baghban, PMP